# SDL - BlitSurface vs LowerBlit

Tags: graphics, rendering, sdl, blit

I just realized that SDL have two functions to blitting. One is [SDL_BlitSurface](https://wiki.libsdl.org/SDL_BlitSurface?highlight=%28%5CbCategorySurface%5Cb%29%7C%28CategoryEnum%29%7C%28CategoryStruct%29) and the second one is [SDL_LowerBlit](https://wiki.libsdl.org/SDL_LowerBlit?highlight=%28%5CbCategorySurface%5Cb%29%7C%28CategoryEnum%29%7C%28CategoryStruct%29). Moreover, both of these functions have their scaled version (SDL_BlitScaled, SDL_LowerBlitScaled). What is difference between these two functions? 
Doc says that LowerBlit "perform a low-level surface blitting only". What should I present under this?

Answer (score 2):

The answer is in documentation under *Remarks* section of both functions.

**SDL_LowerBlit**:

> This is a semi-private blit function and it performs low-level surface blitting, assuming the input rectangles have already been clipped.

**SDL_BlitSurface**:

> This is the public blit function, and it performs rectangle validation and clipping before passing it to SDL_LowerBlit().